# Why give this error message?

Tags: php, oop

I'm very beginner in php..so that I don't understand why give this error message?
Please help me. This is my first question in this site.

```
<?php
class shatil{
var $sat;
    function __construct($my_name){//this is built in construct function
        $this->sat = $my_name;
    }
    function set_sat($me_shatil){
            $this->sat = $me_shatil;//you can Placement anything without'sat'
    }
    function get_sat(){
        return $this->sat;  
    }
}

?>
<?php
$me = new shatil();
$i = new shatil();
$me->set_sat("Muhammad Mohoshin");
$i->set_sat("Habib Shatil");

echo "My middle Name ".$me->get_sat();
echo "<br/>";
echo "My first & last Name ".$i->get_sat();
echo "<br/>";
echo "My Full Name : ".$me->sat." ".$i->sat;
echo "<br/>";
$mamun = new shatil("my name is mamun");
echo $mamun->get_sat();
?>
```

Comment: What is the question? Simply saying that you don't understand, doesn't help us diagnose the problem. Are you getting any errors and [**are you checking for them?**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: You have defined parametrized constructor and doesnt pass an argument.

Comment: ...as is calling someone a jackass, unconstructive and insulting, *somewhat*.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That was supposed to read `PHP 4`. It's amazing what one missing number can do to the meaning of a statement.

Comment: ...and no dessert, I'll just go straight to my room lol @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @JohnConde: Oh, haha. Then carry on ;)

Comment: @JohnConde Even missing a simple *period* will put a damper on anyone's day. In code that is ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is because you don't pass any parameters to your constructor

IT should be:

```
$me = new shatil('name');
$i = new shatil('name2');
```

instead of:

```
$me = new shatil();
$i = new shatil();
```